# Debugging Threads in Android - How can I see in real time number of threads in queue etc

Tags: android

I'm loading a bunch of images using AsyncTasks, creating bitmaps. Lots of recycling views going on etc. Without going into the gory details, I would like to know if there is any way I can get some realtime stats on threads that might be helpful. In particular what I am noticing is that the doInBackground runs really fast once it gets kicked off, but it seems they it takes a while for these tasks to run.  So I was wondering how I can know how many threads are running at a given time. I have seen the dreaded 128 limit on thread exception with 10 in queue, but thats once there is an overload, I would like to be able to watch this as the program is running. Hopefully this visibility will tell me something.   BTW, I did try bumping of the thread priority within the doInBackground() but again its really not that it is not fast once it runs, its that it does not get scheduled to run fast. I'm on Android Studio, what kind of tools are available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When debugging and stopped on a breakpoint you can scroll through all the launched threads and their current execution points (the spinner on the left of the debug tab).

Knowing where your threads are started you can launch method profiling on this method and see how your threads are performing (a "timer" button on the left of the android tab).

Comment: Ok, how is method profiling done? Also is in in the method that launches the async task?

Comment: Ultimately I am launching the AsyncTasks from within getView() of adapter.

Comment: ok, I see there is  // start tracing to "/sdcard/calc.trace"
    Debug.startMethodTracing("calc");
    // ...
    // stop tracing
    Debug.stopMethodTracing();

Comment: @TheMobileGuy what I'm talking about is essentially the [Traceview tool](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html), which has it's own implementation in AS as well, close enough to the DDMS' one. Which one to choose is a matter of personal taste. How it works: you click the timer button, then turn to your device, make it start some task you want to measure, at some point in time you click the timer button again and get a timeline telling you how much time each method was executing, going inside all of its submethods.

Comment: @TheMobileGuy hmm, for this particular task you can use a `long` field in your `AsyncTasks` class, remember execution start time with `System.currentTimeMillis()`, and dump a log message on the execution finish with the difference between that value and current time.